# How to convert pandas dataframe to matrix and export to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
date1     date2     A
2015.1.1  2015.1.2  1
2015.1.1  2015.1.3  2
2015.1.1  2015.1.4  3
2015.1.2  2015.1.3  4
2015.1.2  2015.1.4  5
2015.1.3  2015.1.4  6

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1711 entries, 0 to 1710
Data columns (total 3 columns):
date1    1711 non-null datetime64[ns]
date2    1711 non-null datetime64[ns]
A        1711 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1)
memory usage: 53.5 KB
```

How to convert `df` to a matrix `mx` like this:

```
         2015.1.2 2015.1.3 2015.1.4
2015.1.1    1         2       3
2015.1.2    -         4       5
2015.1.3    -         -       6
```

Then, I need to export `mx` to the Excel or csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic application of pivoting, where one data column becomes the index, another data column is used for the column headers, and the data is distributed in the new `DataFrame` according to the values they were associated with in the original table.

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
      date1     date2  A
0  2015.1.1  2015.1.2  1
1  2015.1.1  2015.1.3  2
2  2015.1.1  2015.1.4  3
3  2015.1.2  2015.1.3  4
4  2015.1.2  2015.1.4  5
5  2015.1.3  2015.1.4  6

In [20]: df.pivot(index="date1", columns="date2", values="A")
Out[20]:
date2    2015.1.2 2015.1.3 2015.1.4
date1
2015.1.1        1        2        3
2015.1.2      NaN        4        5
2015.1.3      NaN      NaN        6
```