# transform table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For example,I have a table like this.
[image]

Then I want to use pandas to transform it like this

[image]

How can I do this.thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31802574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='name', columns='media', values='amount')
```

---

```
df = df.set_index(['name','media')]['amount'].unstack()
```

If duplicates in pairs name and media need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or aggregate with `groupby` and aggregate `mean` can be changed to `sum`, `median`, ..., last reshape by `unstack`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='media', values='amount', aggfunc='mean')
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['name','media')]['amount'].mean().unstack()
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks@jezrael

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.factorize`

```
f1, u1 = pd.factorize(df.name.values)
f2, u2 = pd.factorize(df.media.values)
pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(
        f1 * u2.size + f2, df.amount.values, u1.size * u2.size
    ).reshape(u1.size, u2.size).astype(df.amount.dtype),
    u1, u2
)

         TV  internet  newspaper
andy      6        10         18
steve     8         0          0
richard   0        14          9
```